# jQuery Validation - Error does not display

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jQuery Validation plugin and having a problem displaying the message.

The field itself turns red but the message is nowhere to be seen.

My html code:

```
<div class="dispTbl form-group">
        <div class="dispCell">
            <label>Send discount message within</label>
            <div class="error" id="offerError"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dispCell" style="vertical-align:middle;line-height:20px">
            <div class="InputAddOn">
                <button class="InputAddOn-item" data-action="decrease" data-field="offerDays"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
                <input type="text" name="settings__discount_message_offer_days" id="offerDays" class="days" style="width: 46px" value="<?= $settings__discount_message_offer_days; ?>">
                <button class="InputAddOn-item" data-action="increase" data-field="offerDays"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
var validator = $("#settingsForm").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {
    $("#errors").html("Your form contains " + validator.numberOfInvalids() + " errors, see details below.");
    }).validate({
            debug: true,
            errorElement: "div",
            errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.attr("class") == "days")
                    error.appendTo($('#offerError'));
            },
            success: function(label) {
                    label.text("ok!").addClass("success");
            },
            rules: {
                settings__discount_message_offer_days: {
                    smaller: $('#discApplicableDays').val(),
                    number: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                settings__discount_message_offer_days: {
                    number: 'Please enter a numeric value'
                }
            }
    });
```

The smaller method:

```
    $.validator.addMethod('smaller',function(value, element, param) {
    return value <= param;
}, 'These number of days cannot be bigger than the Discount applicable if paid within number of days');
```

The values the methods gets are:
value: 1
param: 0

Why is the div for the error stays empty?

Comment: Ok, for some reason, the error suddenly displays, but now I have a different problem. It always displays the 'smaller' message and not the number message. If I put 'a' in the field I get the error from the smaller method. Why is that?

Comment: The code as you've posted it is not working at all... the HTML does not even contain `form` tags, a `submit` button, or the `#errors` and `#discApplicableDays` elements.  Please include enough code to properly reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're improperly using all kinds of options without telling us exactly how this is supposed to behave.  You've also neglected to include enough code to reproduce the issue.  There is no `<form>`, a `submit` button, and there is no `#errors` and `#discApplicableDays` elements.

Additionally, these are issues as well.

1. You have [the `errorContainer` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorcontainer) set to `$("#warning, #summary")` and there are no such containers in your code.  Also, this option expects the `errorLabelContainer` to also be set.
2. You have the `errorElement` set to `div` and this is fine.  However, within `errorPlacement`, you are trying to check for a certain element and force that error message to append to another `div` you've manually created.  This is so unnecessary.  If you allow the plugin to operate by default, you can use simple jQuery DOM manipulation to place the `div` anywhere without having to manually create or dynamically append anything.
3. Within errorPlacement, you have `if (element.attr("class") == "days")`. However, when there is an error, the error class is dynamically applied by the plugin, so your conditional is always going to fail since `"days error"` is not going to match `"days"`.  Use [jQuery `.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), which returns a boolean, for checking for the `days` class.  However, as stated in #2 above, I think this approach should be abandoned for something more generic.

Comment: Thank you.
Answering your comments:

Comment: Thank you, answeringThank you.
This helped:
element.hasClass('days')

Comment: @SigalZahavi, you're welcome.  Please accept my answer, by clicking the green checkmark, as item #3 solved your root problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use the showErrors option to accomplish this:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
$(".errormsg").html($.map(errorList, function (el) {
    return el.message;
}).join(", "));
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bd3zM/

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I'm trying to do. I want to display each error next to the field it belongs to, not as a list of all errors together.